# Page not found (404) No Track matches the given query. error Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I'm getting this page not found error when clicking on a link to the eq_detail page. the links are generated by a for loop in the "instrument_detail.html" template , the first link works but the others come back with this error.

error

```
Page not found (404)
No Track matches the given query.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/eq-detail/wonderful/guitar/2/
Raised by:  feed.views.eq_detail
```

not sure what the fault is , here's my url, views and templates

urls.py

```
path('instrument-detail/<slug:track_slug>/<int:id>/', views.instrument_detail, name='instrument_detail'),
path('eq-detail/<slug:track_slug>/<slug:instrument_slug>/<int:id>/', views.eq_detail, name='eq_detail'),
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def instrument_detail(request, track_slug, id):
    user = request.user
    track = get_object_or_404(Track, id=id)
    my_inst = Instrument.objects.filter(track_id=track.id)
    instrument_obj = get_object_or_404(Instrument, id=id)
    if my_inst.exists():
        instruments = Instrument.objects.filter(track_id=track.id)
        context = {
            'instruments': instruments,
            'track': track,
            'instrument': instrument_obj,
        }
        return render(request, 'feed/instrument_detail.html', context)
    else:
        print('There are no instruments set in your track')
        return redirect('create_instrument', track_slug=track.slug, id=track.id)


@login_required
def eq_detail(request, track_slug, instrument_slug, id):
    user = request.user
    track = get_object_or_404(Track, id=id)
    instrument = get_object_or_404(Instrument, id=id)
    eq_obj = get_object_or_404(EQ, id=id)
    eqs = EQ.objects.filter(instrument_id=instrument.id)
    if eqs.exists(): 
        context = {
            'track': track,
            'instrument': instrument,
            'eqs': eqs,
            'eq_obj': eq_obj,
        }
        return render(request, 'feed/eq_detail.html', context)
    else:
        return redirect('create_eq', track_slug=track.slug, instrument_slug=instrument.slug, id=instrument.id)
```

eq_detail.html

```
<a href="{% url 'instrument_detail' track.slug track.id %}"><b>Back To Instruments</b></a>
<br>

<br>

<div class="container my-tracks">
    
    {% if eqs|length >= 1 %}

    <div class="row row-cols-3 row-cols-md-2 g-4">
        {% for item in eqs %}

            <div class="col">
                <div class="card one-track">
                <h5>Eq:   {{ item.id }} </h5>
                <h5>Frequency:   {{ item.frequency }}</h5>
                <h5>Boost:   {{ item.boost }}</h5>
                <h5>Cut:   {{ item.cut }}</h5>

                </div>
            </div>

        {% endfor %}
    </div>

    {% else %}

        <a href="{% url 'create_eq' track.slug instrument.slug item.id %}"><b>Add EQ</b></a>

    {% endif %}
</div>
```

instrument_detail.html

```
<div class="container my-tracks">
    
{% if instruments|length >= 1 %}
    
    <div class="row row-cols-3 row-cols-md-2 g-4">
        {% for item in instruments %}

            <div class="col">
                <div class="card one-track">
                    <a href="{% url 'eq_detail' track.slug item.slug item.id %}"><h5>{{ item.title }}</h5></a>
                </div>
            </div>

        {% endfor %}

        
{% else %}

<a href="{% url 'create_instrument' track.slug track.id %}"><b>Add Instrument</b></a>

{% endif %}
```

Comment: In `eq_detail` you have written `track = get_object_or_404(Track, id=id)` but the id in the url is of the _instrument_ not of the _track_. Also in the same function you have `eq_obj = get_object_or_404(EQ, id=id)` which again is wrong...

Comment: thanks , could you clarify, i wanted to have a url path for eq-detail like: eq-detail/slug:track_slug>/slug:instrument_slug>/int:id>/ , with the id being the eq model id ,  how could i do this ? also i was doing track = get_object_or_404(Track, id=id) in the eq_detail view to get the track.slug in the instrument_detail.html page , is that the correct way of doing it ?

Answer (score 1):

ok, I figured it out, I had to change my eq_detail views to :

```
@login_required
def eq_detail(request, track_slug, instrument_slug, id):
    user = request.user
    try:
        instrument = get_object_or_404(Instrument, id=id)
        eq_obj = EQ.objects.get(id=instrument.id)
        eqs = EQ.objects.filter(instrument_id=instrument.id)
        context = {
            'instrument': instrument,
            'eqs': eqs,
            'eq_obj': eq_obj,
        }
        return render(request, 'feed/eq_detail.html', context)
    except EQ.DoesNotExist:
        return redirect('create_eq', track_slug=instrument.track.slug, instrument_slug=instrument.slug, id=instrument.id)
```

and in my eq_detail.html template change the url link to :

```
<a href="{% url 'create_eq' instrument.track.slug instrument.slug eq_obj.id %}"><b>Add EQ</b></a>
```